# Spring AuthenticationAuditListener add information about target URL

Tags: java, spring

Spring boot actuator provides `AuthenticationAuditListener` class that exposes Spring security authentication events `AbstractAuthenticationEvent`. I'm logging these events using custom event listener.

I was trying to add to those `AbstractAuthenticationEvent` exposed events an additional information about the URL, which requestor tries to connect to. Unfortunately, all my attempts have failed.

My question is if there are the handy way to fill those events with target URL path?

Comment: You can configure a custom `AuthenticationDetailsSource` which creates an extended `WebAuthenticationDetails` to include the URL and other information you want. Then the `Authentication` objct through `getDetails` contains the requested information.

Comment: @M.Deinum, worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As [M.Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) suggested in the comment, providing custom `WebAuthenticationDetails` and `AuthenticationDetailsSource` did the thing.

I've had to create desired WebAuthenticationDetails class

```
public class ExtendedWebAuthenticationDetails extends WebAuthenticationDetails {

    private final String requestUrl;

    public ExtendedWebAuthenticationDetails(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
        this.requestUrl = request.getRequestURI();
    }

    public String getRequestUrl() {
        return requestUrl;
    }
}
```

And use it within custom WebAuthenticationDetailsSource

```
@Component
public class CustomWebAuthenticationDetailsSource extends WebAuthenticationDetailsSource {

    @Override
    public WebAuthenticationDetails buildDetails(HttpServletRequest context) {
        return new ExtendedWebAuthenticationDetails(context);
    }
}
```

In the end, tell Spring security to use the configured authenticationDetailsSource

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityCommonConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private WebAuthenticationDetailsSource detailsSource;

    ...

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().authenticationDetailsSource(detailsSource);
    }
}
```

As a result, all `AbstractAuthenticationEvent` fired events return `ExtendedWebAuthenticationDetails` with `getDetails()` method call. This gives an access to the desired request URL.

Comment: Great answer. Personally, I didn't use basic auth but `formLogin` so I used `authenticationDetailsSource()` from [AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.html#authenticationDetailsSource-org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationDetailsSource-) instead.